# select join result as columns to same row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a one-to-many relation in a pg database. I have table A and table B, where rows of B have a foreign key to A.

I want to select certain rows from A and attach certain columns from matching rows of B to same row from A.

E.g.

```
      A
id | created_at |

      B
id | created_at | a_id | type |
```

I tried to do multiple subqueries, e.g.

```
select A.id,
(select created_at from B where b.a_id = a.id and B.type = 'some_type' limit 1) as some_type_created_at,
(select created_at from B where b.a_id = a.id and B.type = 'another_type' limit 1) as another_type_created_at
from A
```

But this is obviously ugly and wrong, feels like that. What is the better way of achieving it in Postgres?

Ofcourse I can do join and get the full cartesian product, but I want the result from the db to be directly like this.

Comment: Join to table b twice.  Once on `a.created_at = b.created_at and a.id = b.a_id AND b.type = 'SOME_TYPE', once on `a.created_at = b.created_at and a.id = b.a_id AND b.type = 'another_type'`,

Comment: Thanks. Is it more performant?

Comment: What if there are multiple rows in B that match A? Do you want to pick one randomly, or all of them?

Comment: @TheImpaler there’re indeed multiple rows, i wanna pick certain ones, based on a condition and assign their columns as specific columns of the A row

Comment: @TristanTzara Right, but what if there are multiple rows that match the condition `B.type = 'some_type'` for one row in A?

Comment: @TheImpaler let’s assume it’s possible to write a condition (where or limit 1) which would identify only one

Comment: OK, then there's nothing wrong about using scalar subqueries the way you are doing it. That will work well and will give you the result you want. Alternatively, you could use lateral table expressions; that will also give you the same result, it's more complex, and in this case I don't see any particular benefit to use them. In sum, you are good.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks! can you pls post an explained example of using lateral table expressions for this example task?

Comment: @TristanTzara There you go. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong about using scalar subqueries the way you are doing it. That will work well and will give you the result you want.

Alternatively, you could use lateral table expressions; that will also give you the same result, it's more complex, and in this case I don't see any particular benefit to use them. Lateral queries will take the form:

```
select
  a.id,
  b1.created_at as some_type_created_at,
  b2.created_at as another_type_created_at
from a
left join lateral (
  select created_at from B where b.a_id = a.id and B.type = 'some_type' limit 1
) b1 on true,
left join lateral (
  select created_at from B where b.a_id = a.id and B.type = 'another_type' limit 1
) b2 on true
```

In sum, you are good as you are.

Comment: thanks! is there any perf difference between using subqueries vs joining twice vs lateral join?

Comment: I lean to think there isn't. The best way of finding out for sure, is to get both execution plans (prepending `EXPLAIN` to both queries) and comparing them.

Comment: This is pretty much the same as the correlated subquery.